# Advertisement in tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, spam, tag-wiki, advertising

In the [kubernetes tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kubernetes/info) there is some advertisement about a training that is not free. I feel somewhat uneasy about it, but not sure what to do. It's not irrelevant spam, but at the same time others might want their courses featured in this way too.

Is there some clear guidence about tag wiki contents, especially ads?

Comment: The ones on that page both appear to be listed as 'free' as far as I can tell.

Comment: Both are free, however they are 'free' as a means to up-sell you to their paid offerings. Both were added by individuals who don't seem to have any affiliation with the course providers.

Comment: *Both were added by individuals who don't seem to have any affiliation with the course providers* you have literally no way of knowing this

Comment: @Liam of course he can know they don't _seem_ to have any affiliation that's quite easy - note that he never said he is sure they don't have one but the way the motivation _appears_ in this case is meaningful for the discussion.

Comment: I think unmarked ads should not be allowed since unmarked ads are legal issue in some contries. This would create a risk for stackoverflow as a plattform where stackoverflow could be legally responsible for such ads in the future when laws change.